# PostgreSQL extract values between brackets

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a string in PostgreSQL 11:

```
'for values from ('2022-01-01') to ('2023-01-01')'
```

And I need to extract all values between brackets:

expected result: '2022-01-01', '2023-01-01'

If I use the following construction, I'm able to extract only the first value:

```
select substring('FOR VALUES FROM (''2020-01-01'') TO (''2021-01-01'')' from '\((.*?)\)');
```

Is it possible to extract the second value? Or both values as one array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_match()`:

```
select regexp_matches('for values from (''2022-01-01'') to (''2023-01-01'')', '\((.[^)]+)\)', 'g')
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one level of parenthesis than you can use `regexp_matches()` with the `g` (global) flag.

```
SELECT *
       FROM regexp_matches('for values from (''2022-01-01'') to (''2023-01-01'')', '\([^\)]*\)', 'g');
```

Otherwise, if there are more levels, that'll get messy results though. In such a case you need to define which is the level you're after and regular expressions might be of limited use in such a case.